# Company Directory Tree not building properly

Tags: peoplesoft

I am building company directory tree in Peoplesoft 9.2 DMO environment. We have loaded custom data for exploration purposes.

Can any one please tell reasons why the tree is not displaying all the nodes?

In the tree builder run control page, I am using `by supervisor id` and have provided an `emplid` as root node which has many number of reportees and each of them have further reportees.

Answer (score 0):

Go to navigation

> Main Menu > Set Up HCM > Common Definitions > Direct Reports for Managers > Invoke Direct Reports API

Select Class method as drill down and Navigation method as Supervisor. Fill Employee ID and Execute method. If you don't get any Direct reportee then there is some problem with data.

Tree builder process uses this API to build Company Directory Tree.